# How can I make a gradient background for a graphics box in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, background, wolfram-mathematica, gradient

I have seen an answer to this problem for plots, but I want to do it for a general graphics box.

```
Graphics[{Disk[], Red, Rectangle[{-.75, 1}, {.5, -.5}]}, 
 Background -> Green]
```

I would like to make the background of this graphic resemble one of the color palette gradients.  Ideally I would type "RainbowColors" somewhere in the code and the background would look like the RainbowColors palette.

I could remove the background and make a rectangle with a gradient fill, but it's not exactly what I'd like.  I'm hoping someone has a beautiful bit of knowledge.

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I am aware of is this combination of [`Prolog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Prolog.html), [`Polygon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Polygon.html), [`VertexColors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VertexColors.html), and [`Scaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Scaled.html) coordinates:

```
Graphics[
 {Disk[], Red, Rectangle[{-.75, 1}, {.5, -.5}]},
 Prolog ->
  Polygon[
   Scaled /@ {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}},
   VertexColors -> {Yellow, Green, Magenta, Pink}
  ]
]
```

[image]

More complicated gradients can be formed by stacking Polygons:

```
Graphics[
 {Disk[], Red, Rectangle[{-.75, 1}, {.5, -.5}]},
 Prolog ->
  {Polygon[
    Scaled /@ {{0, 0}, {0, 1/2}, {1, 1/2}, {1, 0}},
    VertexColors -> {Red, Yellow, Pink, Blue}
   ],
   Polygon[
    Scaled /@ {{0, 1/2}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1/2}},
    VertexColors -> {Yellow, Green, Magenta, Pink}
   ]}
]
```

[image]

If you struggle with turning this into a function let me know where you had trouble and I will try to help.

---

Please ask your future questions on the dedicated *Mathematica* StackExchange site:

[image]

Comment: Huge thanks.  That should get me what I want.  I will absolutely use the Mathematica StackExchange.  I didn't realize it existed.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Paul I'm glad I could help.  Again, let me know if you need help implementing this.  See you at [Mathematica.SE]! :-)